# Postfix installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

How do I fix this error on Ubuntu 10.04 ?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postfix is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libcap2 apache2.2-bin libapr1 libaprutil1-ldap libaprutil1 php5-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postfix (2.7.0-1) ...

Postfix configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 202002
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: 202002
dpkg: error processing postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even if I reboot, the same error shows up.
Thanks for the help..

Comment: sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf && /etc/init.d/postfix reload worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it clearly states the error is in /etc/postfix/main.cf. Open it and fix `myhostname` value to match `hostname` command. Then run `service postfix reload` and check how it is.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by configuring an invalid hostname on first installation. The `debconf` keeps the values in its database and uses those for future installations also (I guess?), which causes this problems even if you remove or/and purge your postfix.

Try to purge your configuration with following command `echo PURGE | debconf-communicate postfix` and try `apt-get install postfix` again.